# Simple Derivative paradox

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I define $y(x)=x^3$

$${dy(x) \over dx} = 3x^2$$

$${dy(x) \over dy} = 1 = 3x^2 \frac{dx}{dy} = 0\text{ since }x \neq f(y)$$

$1 \neq 0$

If you take the differential $d()$ where $dy(x)$ then there is no issues since the derivative definition isn't explicitly used and it results in a $\dfrac{dx}{dy(x)}$.  Why does this paradox exist?  Thank you!!

Comment: I don't see how you got $ \frac {\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}y} = 1 = 3x^2 \cdot \frac {\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}y} = 0 $?

Comment: The statement $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=0$ has nothing at all to recommend it.  Did somebody think that that statement is true?  Why would they think that? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\lim x(y+dy)-x(y) \over dy$ = 0 where x doesn't vary on a y variation which you guys say is incorrect because $x(y)$ which I never defined which I suppose is defined implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $\frac{dx}{dy}$ isn't $0$; since $x = y^{1/3}$, we have $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{3} y^{-2/3} = \frac{1}{3x^2}$. The same sort of argument holds for arbitrary $y(x)$ (modulo being careful about the uniqueness of inverses, which isn't relevant to the paradox you present).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you think $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$?

$x$ can be made dependent on $y$ by simple rearrangement, to give $x = y^{\frac 13}$, so everything should work out nicely.

Comment: So it's entirely acceptable to write $y(x)$ and $x(y)$.  I've never seen this done before except in terms of thermodynamics.  The functions are kept consistent i.e. y(x) is only referenced as such and no nested $y(x(y))$.